# Solving equation with delay term

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I am trying to solve an equation looks like this...

```
x[t] == t^2 + x[t-10]
```

How can I obtain a numerical solution for x[t] in Mathematica?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please explore the `RSolve` command from the docs. Consider evaluating: `RSolve[{x[t] == t^2 + x[t - 1], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]`

Comment: @Syed Clever! I'm wondering why `RSolve[{x[t] == t^2 + x[t - 10] }, x[t], t]` doesn't evaluate directly?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am guessing (not sure) that it would require many more initial conditions.

Comment: @Syed Thanks! Possibly yes, but it remains strange that delay `10` makes problems compared to delay `1`. Mathematica should be able to detect this simple transformation `  x -> ( X[#/10] &) /. t -> 10 \[Tau]` which makes the equation solvable.

Comment: Mathematica 13 on Windows 10 easily cracks `RSolve[x[t] == t^2 + x[t - 8], x, t]`, but stops at `RSolve[x[t]==t^2+x[t-9],x,t]`, returning a warning "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50. reached while evaluating Log[Cos[\[Pi]/18]^2+Sin[\[Pi]/18]^2]" and the input.

Comment: For comparison, the command of Maple 2022 `allvalues(rsolve(x(t) = t^2 + x(t - 10), x(t)))` produces a long result in a short time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Syed clever comment, I'll show how  to solve the original delay equation OP asked for.

Unfortunately Mathematica doesn't solve `RSolve[x[t] == t^2 + x[t-10],x,t]` directly (don't know why...).

Transformation `t -> 10 \[Tau],x[t]->X[\[Tau]]` gives a solvable equation

```
eq\[Tau] = x[t] == t^2 + x[t - 10 ] /. x -> ( X[#/10] &) /. t -> 10 \[Tau] //Simplify
```

$100 \tau ^2+X(\tau -1)=X(\tau )$

```
RSolve[{eq\[Tau]}, X[\[Tau]], \[Tau]]
```

$\left\{\left\{X(\tau )\to -\frac{50}{3} (-\tau -1) \left(2 \tau^2+\tau \right)+c_1\right\}\right\}$

Comment: I think you find only a partial solution. Compare with the answer by me.

Answer (score 2):

We can get a solution using $n$ instead of 10.  We want a solution for `x[t]` and a solution for `x[t-n]` so we can check the solution by back-substitution:

```
sol = RSolve[x[t] == t^2 + x[t - n], x[t], t] // Flatten // First
soln = sol /. t -> t - n
check = x[t] == t^2 + x[t - n] /. sol /. soln // Simplify

(*  x[t] -> -(1/6) n^2 (-1 - t/n) (t/n + (2 t^2)/n^2) + C[1]  *)

(*  x[-n + t] -> -(1/6)
       n^2 (-1 - (-n + t)/n) ((-n + t)/n + (2 (-n + t)^2)/n^2) + C[1]  *)

(*  True  *)
```

To get the solution for `n=10`, use `ReplaceAll`:

```
sol /. n -> 10 // Simplify

(*  x[t] -> (5 t)/3 + t^2/2 + t^3/30 + C[1]  *)
```

In this final form it is easy to identify the constant `C[1]` as `x[0]`.

Comment: Using `X = RSolveValue[x[t] == t^2 + x[t - n], x, t];X[t] /. n -> 10` might simplify your answer. Any idea  why Mathematica solves for variable `n` but not for fixed `n=10` `RSolveValue[x[t] == t^2 + x[t - 10], x, t]` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I have no idea why Mathematica is doing this.

Comment: Thank you, still strange Mathematica behavior...

Comment: I think you find only  a partial solution. Compare with the answer by me.

Answer (score 1):

Another (true) way is as follows.

```
ZTransform[x[t] - t^2 - x[t - 10] == 0, t, z]
```

> `-((z (1 + z))/(-1 + z)^3) - x[-10] - x[-9]/z - x[-8]/z^2 - x[-7]/z^3 - x[-6]/z^4 - x[-5]/z^5 - x[-4]/z^6 - x[-3]/z^7 - x[-2]/z^8 - x[-1]/ z^9 + ZTransform[x[t], t, z] - ZTransform[x[t], t, z]/z^10 == 0`

```
Solve[%, ZTransform[x[t], t, z]];
InverseZTransform[ZTransform[x[t], t, z] /. First[%], z,  t] // Simplify
```

> `50 (2 + 2 (-1)^(1/5) - (-1)^(2/5) + (-1)^(4/5)) t +  15 (2 + 2 (-1)^(1/5) - (-1)^(2/5) + (-1)^(4/5)) t^2 + (2 +  2 (-1)^(1/5) - (-1)^(2/5) + (-1)^(4/5)) t^3 +  3 (4 (-1)^(2 t/5) + 20 (-1)^(3 t/5) + 5 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) +  5 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) + 2 (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) +  10 (-1)^((2 + t)/5) + 5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) +  5 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) + 10 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) + 2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) - 20 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) +  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) + 5 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) - 2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) -  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t + 3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t -  5 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) - 20 (-(-1)^(2/5))^t +  20 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t - 5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t +  5 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) - 5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) -  4 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t + 4 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t -  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t - 3 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) -  10 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t - 5 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t +  10 (-(-1)^(4/5))^( 1 + t) + (2 + 2 (-1)^(1/5) - (-1)^(2/5) + (-1)^(4/5) +  4 (-1)^(t/5) - 4 (-1)^(2 t/5) + 8 (-1)^(3 t/5) + 2 (-1)^t +  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) - (-1)^(2/5 + t) + (-1)^(4/5 + t) -  7 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) - 6 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) - (-1)^(( 4 (1 + t))/5) + (-1)^((2 + t)/5) - 5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) -  2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) + 3 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) +  8 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) - 3 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) +  6 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) - 4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) +  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) + 7 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) +  4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) + 2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) +  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) + 8 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t -  4 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t +  7 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t + 6 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) +  4 (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) - 3 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t +  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t + (-(-1)^(4/5))^( 1 + t) + (-(-1)^(2/5))^ t (-4 + 8 (-1)^(1/5) - 7 (-1)^(2/5) + 6 (-1)^(3/5) -  5 (-1)^(4/5)) + (-(-1)^(1/5))^ t (4 + (-1)^(2/5) - 2 (-1)^(3/5) +  3 (-1)^(4/5))) x[-10] + (2 + 2 (-1)^(1/5) - (-1)^( 2/5) + (-1)^(4/5) + (-1)^(t/5) - 4 (-1)^(2 t/5) -  3 (-1)^(3 t/5) - 2 (-1)^t - 2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) + (-1)^( 2/5 + t) - (-1)^(4/5 + t) - 2 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) + (-1)^(( 3 (1 + t))/5) - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) - (-1)^((2 + t)/5) -  5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) + 2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) -  3 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) + 3 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) -  3 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) + (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) +  4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) - 5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) -  2 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) + 5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) +  3 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t - 4 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t +  2 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t + (-(-1)^(3/5))^( 1 + t) + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) +  3 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t - (-(-1)^(4/5))^( 1 + t) + (-(-1)^(1/5))^ t (-1 + (-1)^(2/5) - 2 (-1)^(3/5) + 3 (-1)^(4/5)) + (-(-1)^( 2/5))^t (4 - 3 (-1)^(1/5) + 2 (-1)^(2/5) - (-1)^(3/5) +  5 (-1)^(4/5))) x[-9] + 2 x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-8] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-8] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-8] - (-1)^(t/5) x[-8] + (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-8] -  2 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-8] + 2 (-1)^t x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-8] - (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-8] + (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-8] -  2 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-8] - (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-8] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-8] + (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-8] -  2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-8] - 2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-8] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-8] + (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-8] + (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-8] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-8] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-8] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-8] + (-1)^( 2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-8] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-8] + (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-8] + (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-8] -  2 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-8] +  2 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-8] -  2 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-8] + (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-8] + (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-8] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-8] +  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-8] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-8] + 2 x[-7] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-7] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-7] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-7] + (-1)^(t/5) x[-7] + (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-7] +  2 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-7] - 2 (-1)^t x[-7] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-7] + (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-7] - (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-7] + 3 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-7] -  4 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-7] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-7] - (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-7] +  5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-7] - 3 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-7] +  2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-7] - 2 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-7] +  2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-7] -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-7] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-7] +  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-7] +  3 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-7] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-7] -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-7] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-7] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-7] + (-1)^( 2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-7] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-7] +  4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-7] - (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-7] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-7] -  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-7] +  3 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-7] -  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-7] -  2 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-7] + (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-7] -  3 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-7] -  4 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-7] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-7] -  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-7] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-7] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-7] + 2 x[-6] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-6] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-6] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-6] - (-1)^(t/5) x[-6] + 6 (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-6] -  7 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-6] + 2 (-1)^t x[-6] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-6] - (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-6] + (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-6] + 8 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-6] +  4 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-6] + 4 (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-6] -  4 (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-6] + 5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-6] +  3 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-6] - 2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-6] -  7 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-6] + 2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-6] -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-6] + 6 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-6] -  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-6] -  8 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-6] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-6] -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-6] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-6] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-6] -  4 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-6] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-6] -  4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-6] + 6 (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-6] -  7 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-6] +  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-6] -  8 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-6] -  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-6] - 7 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-6] +  6 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-6] -  8 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-6] -  4 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-6] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-6] +  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-6] -  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-6] -  4 (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-6] + 2 x[-5] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-5] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-5] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-5] -  4 (-1)^(t/5) x[-5] - 4 (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-5] -  8 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-5] - 2 (-1)^t x[-5] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-5] + (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-5] - (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-5] - 7 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-5] +  6 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-5] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-5] - (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-5] -  5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-5] + 2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-5] -  3 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-5] + 8 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-5] -  3 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-5] + 6 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-5] +  4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-5] - 5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-5] -  7 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-5] + 4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-5] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-5] + 3 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-5] +  4 (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-5] + (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-5] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-5] -  6 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-5] + 4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-5] -  8 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-5] +  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-5] -  7 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-5] +  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-5] + 8 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-5] -  4 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-5] +  7 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-5] +  6 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-5] -  4 (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-5] +  3 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-5] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-5] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-5] + 2 x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-4] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-4] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-4] - (-1)^(t/5) x[-4] - 4 (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-4] +  3 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-4] + 2 (-1)^t x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-4] - (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-4] + (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-4] -  2 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-4] - (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-4] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-4] + (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-4] -  5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-4] - 2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-4] +  3 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-4] + 3 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-4] -  3 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-4] + (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-4] -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-4] + 5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-4] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-4] +  3 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-4] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-4] + (-1)^( 2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-4] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-4] + (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-4] - 4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-4] +  3 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-4] -  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-4] +  2 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-4] +  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-4] + 3 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-4] -  4 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-4] + (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-4] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-4] -  3 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-4] +  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-4] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-4] + 2 x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-3] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-3] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-3] + (-1)^(t/5) x[-3] + (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-3] - 2 (-1)^t x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-3] + (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-3] - (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-3] -  2 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-3] + (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-3] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-3] - (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-3] +  2 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-3] + 2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-3] + (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-3] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-3] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-3] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-3] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-3] + (-1)^( 2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-3] - (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-3] - (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-3] -  2 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-3] -  2 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-3] + (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-3] +  2 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-3] + (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-3] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-3] -  2 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-3] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-3] + 2 x[-2] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-2] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-2] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-2] - (-1)^(t/5) x[-2] + (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-2] -  2 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-2] + 2 (-1)^t x[-2] +  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-2] - (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-2] + (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-2] + 3 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-2] +  4 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-2] - (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-2] + (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-2] +  5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-2] + 3 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-2] -  2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-2] - 2 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-2] +  2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-2] -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-2] + (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-2] -  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-2] -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-2] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-2] -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-2] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-2] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-2] + (-1)^( 2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-2] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-2] -  4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-2] + (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-2] -  2 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-2] +  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-2] -  3 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-2] -  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-2] -  2 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-2] + (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-2] -  3 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-2] -  4 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-2] - (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-2] +  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-2] -  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-2] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-2] + 2 x[-1] +  2 (-1)^(1/5) x[-1] - (-1)^(2/5) x[-1] + (-1)^(4/5) x[-1] + (-1)^(t/5) x[-1] + 6 (-1)^(2 t/5) x[-1] +  7 (-1)^(3 t/5) x[-1] - 2 (-1)^t x[-1] -  2 (-1)^(1/5 + t) x[-1] + (-1)^(2/5 + t) x[-1] - (-1)^(4/5 + t) x[-1] + 8 (-1)^((2 (1 + t))/5) x[-1] -  4 (-1)^((3 (1 + t))/5) x[-1] + 4 (-1)^((4 (1 + t))/5) x[-1] +  4 (-1)^((2 + t)/5) x[-1] + 5 (-1)^((2 (2 + t))/5) x[-1] -  3 (-1)^((3 + t)/5) x[-1] + 2 (-1)^((4 + t)/5) x[-1] -  7 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-1] + 2 (-1)^(2/5 (1 + 2 t)) x[-1] -  4 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 2 t)) x[-1] - 6 (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 3 t)) x[-1] +  5 (-1)^(1/5 (2 + 3 t)) x[-1] +  8 (-1)^(1/5 (4 + 3 t)) x[-1] - (-1)^(1/5 (1 + 4 t)) x[-1] -  3 (-1)^(1/5 (3 + 4 t)) x[-1] -  2 (-(-1)^(1/5))^(-1 + t) x[-1] - (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-1] -  4 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-1] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(1/5))^t x[-1] +  4 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(-1 + t) x[-1] - 6 (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-1] +  7 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-1] -  5 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(2/5))^t x[-1] +  8 (-(-1)^(2/5))^(1 + t) x[-1] -  5 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(-1 + t) x[-1] - 7 (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-1] +  6 (-1)^(1/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-1] -  8 (-1)^(4/5) (-(-1)^(3/5))^t x[-1] -  4 (-(-1)^(3/5))^(1 + t) x[-1] + (-(-1)^(4/5))^(-1 + t) x[-1] -  2 (-1)^(2/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-1] +  3 (-1)^(3/5) (-(-1)^(4/5))^t x[-1] +  4 (-(-1)^(4/5))^(1 + t) x[-1]))/(30 (1 + (-1)^(1/5))^2 (2 -  2 (-1)^(1/5) + (-1)^(2/5)))`